# Android spinner value gets lost when i open new activity?

Tags: android

Android spinner value gets lost when i open new activity and come back from that activity to my previous one.how do i retain my spinner index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use activity life cycle methods to save the state of the Activity and restore the Activity state to the previous state. those methods are `onPause(), onResume()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html  follow this link

Answer (score 1):

You can override the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods in the Activity class and save/restore the value of your index.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)